# Calling different jQuery/JS for different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a website with multiple javascripts firing on different pages, each page with different scripts.

I want to have a single js file with all the functions but I don't want to have to declare every javascript file on pages where I don't use that script.

I added different classes (based on the scripts used on each page) and I'm using this method:

```
    if($('body').is('.wowJS')){     
         ....
     }
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this? Are there any other methods?

Comment: You need separate files to take advantage of Browser caching. Organising them is down to how functionality is organised on your website. Have a look at *bundling* to reduce the number of file transfer requests (which is what I think you really want to do).

Comment: It is not efficient to have a large js-file with alot of code that is not used on specific page. The browser will still need to parse the code even if it's never user. Separate the javascript content to relevant files and add reference to pages where needed.

Comment: Either bundle the scripts in a single file and use the caching behavior of browser or use require js.

Comment: I second the use or requirejs; it takes a little googling to learn how to use it properly but when you figure it out loading in resources on demand is almost no effort.

Comment: Got it! Separating files makes a lot of sense and I was first considering that. However, I'm trying to build a website template for themeforest and I've noticed that the best practice there is to use one large JS file. I think it's because it's easier to grasp for customers...?

Comment: RequireJS itself is probably larger than all your scripts together. If you don't want to go the single page app route, it makes the most sense to put the stuff that is specific to a page in its own file and only load it when required. You can still have a common file for stuff that you use on most pages.

Comment: Could place pieces in single json object, or function returning object(s); or, object for each page . See, e.g., `window.jQuery. // with "."` at console , `var scripts = {"page1":{"a":function(){return 10 * 20},"b":function() {console.log(scripts.page1.a())}}}`

Answer (score 1):

used this code execute javascript for specific page.

```
var route = {
    _routes: {}, // The routes will be stored here

    add: function (url, action) {
    this._routes[url] = action;
    },
    run: function () {
        jQuery.each(this._routes, function (pattern) {
        if (location.href.match(pattern)) {
            // "this" points to the function to be executed
            this();
        }
    });
  }
}

// Will execute only on this page:
route.add('002.html',function (){
alert("Hello"); 
});

// You can even use regex-es:
route.add('.*.html',function (){
alert("Hellodaa"); 
});

route.run();
```